# Custom migration operation with Mysql in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

It's a simple question: is it possible to create a custom migration operation for mysql utilizing the `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator`? As the `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator` class doesn't implement a `Statement` method like the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` does, how's possible for me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `Generete` methods from the `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator` and get a method along the lines of:

```
protected override MigrationStatement Generate(CreateTableOperation op) => base.Generate(op);
```

The `MigrationStatement` has an `Sql` string porperty. You can add your own Sql to this `Sql` property. IE:

```
protected override MigrationStatement Generate(CreateTableOperation op)
{
    MigrationStatement statement = base.Generate(op);

    if(/*Your condition */)
    {
        statement.Sql += $@"; {/*Your Sql*/};";
    }

    return statement;
}
```